# What should I use instead of floats in Bootstrap 4

Tags: flexbox

I get that you don't need to use floats to have columns line up horizontally because Bootstrap 4 uses flexbox. However, what if I want to float an image to the right (for example) and have the text wrap around the image? I see BS 4 has float classes that will achieve this. But is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Please paste a snippet of what HTML you got so far

Answer (score 0):

Since flexbox allows you to acheive all manner of layouts with out using `float` I would advice against it.

Using raw CSS flex box you would acheive this by having a div, and then specifying

`justify-content: flex-end`

If you have a flex div with a direction of row which is taking up some space. Choosing flex-end will make content shift up to the end.

Please see [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for reference of this and checkout justify-content

It seems that this is achievable using bootstrap by using

`<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">...</div>`

Please see the [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) for more information

Its well worth reading the css-tricks article from beginning to end to understand everything that is possible to achieve with flex box. Then with the bootstrap docs you will gain a deeper understanding of whats happening under the hood.

Comment: But this will not allow the text to wrap around the div that is displaying flex-end, correct? It will act as a column that takes up the full height, preventing the text from wrapping.

Comment: What I do in situations where I'm stuck in flex box, is sketch out on paper exactly what I want to achieve, then think logically how the divs are going to work together. Some divs wil have direction row, some will have direction column, some will grow to fill the volume of their container, some will take up a proportion of the container, some will go to then end (justify flex end). In order to harness the power of flexbox you need to first understand it. I guarantee you once you understand the css tricks guide I posted above and flick through  the bootstrap docs you'll be making your layout

Comment: Thanks Max. I'm very familiar with that site and reference it all the time, it's great. I also like the idea of drawing things out. What I'm trying to achieve (having the text wrap around the div containing the image) requires a float. I found several other articles here asking the same question. I guess that's why Bootstrap 4 has the float classes. :-)